# Dynamics AX 2009 Rollup 7 Enterprise Portal AX_Core ERROR using Windows server 2008 r2 64 bits and sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: enterprise, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009, ax, enterprise-portal

Arquitecture:

AOS Server: Running windows server 2008 r2 std 64 bits spanish.

Enterprise Portal Server: Running windows server 2008 r2 std 64 bits spanish, SharePoint 2010 Foundation 64 bits, IIS 7.5

DataBase server: Running Window server 2008 r2 std 64 bits spanish, SQL Server 2008 std r2 64 bits spanish, Reporting Services  and analysis services both 2008 r2 64 bits spanish.

Issue:

After update to Dynamics AX 2009 Rollup 7 we are experiencing the following error. This is the first time EP portal is implemented and deployed. I have try so many suggestions but non deals with this.

EP Users are not able to navigate through the EP pages. Below is the snapshot of the error which comes up in the EP Page. Sharepoint as usual doesn't show informative/descriptive errors and it's quite difficult to debug sharepoint pages, so my next bet was to look into Event Viewer to get a more detailed description of the error.

Event Viewer Log:
Dynamics Object Adapter Call failed Thread was being aborted
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
   at AxCore_Call(UInt64 , Char* , tagVARIANT* , Int32 , tagVARIANT* )
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.AxaptaObject.Call(String methodName, Object[] paramList)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Session.DynamicsObjectAdapter.Call(String methodName)

Microsoft Dynamics AX Business Connector Session 444.

Thread was being aborted.
   at AxCore_Call(UInt64 , Char* , tagVARIANT* , Int32 , tagVARIANT* )
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.AxaptaObject.Call(String methodName, Object[] paramList)

Session Release for Microsoft Dynamics failed.

No .NET Business Connector session could be found.

Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Session.Exceptions.NoKernelSessionException
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Session.DynamicsSession.get_AxaptaAdapter()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Portal.AxWebSession.WebSessionClientRemove()
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Session.DynamicsSession.Release(ICacheContext context)

I can provide additional details if needed. This seems like a bug to me, can any body help or confirm?.

Answer (score 1):

I would first retract solution and deploy it again. 
On sharepoint 2010 it's at Central Admin>system settings>farm management>Manage farm solutions. Read more here: http://www.techgrowingpains.com/2010/07/adding-deploying-removing-and-most-all-things-involving-solutions-and-sharepoint-2010/

You could then also try to update the web parts again. Navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\50\Setup and run AxUpdatePortal.exe -updateWebSites -iisreset. Read more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2009/05/13/updating-enterprise-portal-from-dynamics-ax-2009-client-fails-on-a-64bit-microsoft-windows-server.aspx

Comment: Hello , i try both suggestions, same result when trying to browse EP. Please help!! I have opened a Microsoft Support ticket, will post my results here and here https://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33/p/54683/98665.aspx .

Comment: Could you please verify the business connector is set to connect to the correct AOS on the correct port. Go to Start->Control Panel. Open Administrative Tools and then the Dynamics AX Configuration. View the Business Connector settings there.

Comment: Hello skaue, thank you for joining this question, i have verified that aos client and bussiness conector are pointing to the correct aos and port, we only have one AOS running, i have triple check this in all three servers, aos, ep, and sql servers. I have been working with Microsoft with this, they cant find a solution yet neither do i. I suspect this has to be with windows server 2008 r2 64 .net components and kerberos configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the key to your issue lies in this:

> No .NET Business Connector session could be found.

I have seen this crop up a number of times. On the server where EP is installed, go to the AX Configuration Utility and change the configuration Target to Business Connector (non interactive use).

Ensure that the configuration information is set correctly and that it can connect to your AOS. BC will use whatever settings are stored here. If you have not changed them since the installation, you will not be able to make the needed connections to AX.